# Understanding a symbol in the proof of tube lemma

Tags: general-topology, notation

Here is the proof of tube lemma from ncatlab:

> [image]

I do not understand what is the symbol between $U$ and $W$ in the first line, could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Do you want an explanation of the definition or of the name and pronunciation of the symbol?

Comment: @CyclotomicField all of these please

Comment: Why this complication? Just choose some $V$ so that $U\times V\subset W$.

Comment: @Mariano: They chose the largest. Justifying the existence of a largest seems unnecessary to me. But it is “canonical.”

Comment: What is ncatlab ? A laboratory with $n$ cats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\multimap$ (as used in this proof) is defined in the first sentence of the proof: for an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U \multimap W$ is the largest open set $V$ in $Y$ such that $U \times V \subseteq W$.

The symbol $\multimap$ has latex code \multimap. I don't think this notation is standard; at least I have never seen it used in a textbook or anywhere else.

Here's something interesting to think about: why is $U \multimap W$ defined? That is, why should there be a largest (in the sense that it contains all others) open set $V$ in $Y$ satisfying $U \times V \subseteq W$? (Hint: the union of arbitrary open sets is still open.)